# copy and paste data when 2 columns matches from different workbooks

Tags: macros

need your expertise, I'm totally new to Excel Macros.  I would like to create a macro that will do the following:
I have 2 workbooks (WB1 and WB2). Both workbooks will have the same values of entries in column A. I would like the macro to match column A of WB1 and the cell value in column A of WB2. If matched, it will copy cells D:F from the WB2 to WB1 and paste on the cell J.  Appreciate your help, many thanks.

Comment: *I would like the macro* ... and you want us to write this macro instead of you?